# Application Builder in Marklogic 8

Tags: marklogic

Are Information Studio and Application builder still available in Marklogic 8? And if so, how can we access them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I checked they are still there, but you will have to use a direct link. If you are running MarkLogic locally, it would be:

```
http://localhost:8000/appservices/
```

Don't expect improvements though.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

Also understand that to help developers get started, as part of the MarkLogic 8 effort, MarkLogic also has what they call SampleStack - a way for developers to get sample apps up and running using various technologies.

The first 2 are 3-tier apps based on java or node.js.

The public link is here: https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-samplestack

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, the reason they aren't linked is because they are deprecated and will be removed in a future release (says the doc).